# How to run a cursor with PCL SQLite Xamarin

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, cursor, portable-class-library

For the life of me I cannot find any example for going through all rows one by one using a cursor. I have installed the SQLite.Net.PCL from Kreuger and I need a way to use this package in a PCL and read data from my tables already stored in the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SQLite.Net.PCL` is an ORM that provides a higher level view of SQLite, so the low level `C` API for using "step" to "cursor" through each row in a table becomes:

```
var tableQuery = sqlConn.Table<SomeTable>();
foreach (var aSingleRow in tableQuery)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(aSingleRow.SomeColumn);
}
```

If you really want to skip this higher level API and use the SQLite `C` API in `C#`, you should look at `SQLitePCL.Ugly` which a very thin C# binding on top of the `C` API.

Update:

Obtaining the columns of a table:

```
var columnInfo = sqlConn.GetTableInfo("SomeTable");
foreach (var aColumn in columnInfo)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(aColumn.Name);
}
```

Comment: This sounds like a great start! Say I do not know the table structure,all I know is the table name, how can I still use your sample?  I should discover the field names on the go so to speak, like a cursor! Your help is greatly appreciated this morning.

Comment: @Marionette In using most ORMs in C# you would create a C# class that represents the the Table structure using properties for each column in the Table, see my updated answer to obtain the columns of a table via `GetTableInfo`

Comment: But then how do I create the actual class dynamically in order to pull all my values with a cursor?  I get the column names dynamically, I get this, but how do I run a cursor without a class being defined.